# Exporting an exchange public folder contact list to Excel/Access

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders, outlook-2010

How can I export an Exchange 2007 public folder (IPM.Contact) as an Excel or Access file?  We use Outlook 2010 on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Export wizard in Outlook 2010.  If is kind of buried .. File/Options .. on the Advanced tab. The choices for output format include csv and Excel 97-2003.

HOWEVER, I don't think it is possible to run the "Export" wizard over the public folders, only over your mailbox or mail files.

So, for a one off, copy the public folder into a sub-folder in your mailbox (or into a PST) and then run the wizard.  Automating it will take some effort ..

Answer (score 1):

We have used Public Folder contact lists as distribution lists (bad practice, I know), but this worked for me.

Open the contact list.  Save as a text file.  Open the text file with excel. The contact name and the email address will be in two different columns.

Answer (score 0):

Tomjedrz is correct.  You cannot export Public Folder contents to a CSV / Excel document (there is no support for exporting to an access file).  However, you can export Public Folder contents to a .PST file as indicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a is a tool called Outlook Tools which can Export pf contacts to xls.

Comment: Where can you find this tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy

Highlight an ordinary folder within Public Folders (not a contacts folder) then go through the motions of export to file. You will be prompted with the folder selector, accept this time you will be able to browse all of Public Folders and select the PF Contacts folder that you want to export.

Bada-Bing, Bada-Boom!